# Using matching document original score in filter script for custom filters score query

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to use "custom filters score" query and use filters to control the score of resulting documents.

I want a way to use the document's original score as computed by ElasticSearch, and then use that score to calculate the final score of the document, which matches the given filters.

Something like "_docScore * 50/100" as a script for a filter, where "_docScore" is the original score of a document that matches the filter.

How to achieve this in ElasticSearch?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Regards & Thanks,
Aditya.

Answer (score 0):

Documents in a filtered query would be unranked and have the same score.

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/custom-score-query/

But you can use a custom score query together with a filtered query and use a script to calculate a score based on the document values. This was added in 0.90, I believe.